# number of permutations maximizing a sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, contest-math

> Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than $1$. Find the number of permutations $\sigma$ of the set $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ for which $|\sigma(1) - 1| + |\sigma(2) - 2|+\cdots + |\sigma(n) - n| = \frac{n^2 - 1}2$.

I found the solution below from a book, but I have some questions:

- Why is $\frac{n^2 - 1}2$ the maximum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n |\sigma(i) - i|$? I find it hard to prove this formally as $\sigma(i)$ is a bijection. For instance, it might not be true that $|\sigma(i) - i|\leq \frac{1}n (n^2 - 1)/2$ for all $i$.
- Why must $\{\sigma((n+2)/2),\sigma((n+5)/2),\cdots, \sigma(n)\}\subset \{1,2,\cdots, (n+1)/2\}$ and why must $\{\sigma(1),\cdots, \sigma((n-1) / 2)\}\subset \{(n+1) / 2, \cdots n\}$?
- If $\sigma((n+1)/2) = k\leq (n+1)/2$, then how can one verify that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\sigma(i) - i|$ indeed achieves the maximum value? I'm not sure if $\sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} |\sigma(i) - i|$ and $\sum_{i=(n+3)/2}^{n} |\sigma(i) - i|$ have values only dependent on $k$.

I've also read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194195/maximizing-sum-n-inmfn-n-where-fn-is-a-permuation-of-m) but I'm still unsure how to answer my questions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194195/maximizing-sum-n-inmfn-n-where-fn-is-a-permuation-of-m?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't provide enough detail for me to fully understand the answer in the question. This question is focused on exactly how many permutations achieve the equality case, which the answer you linked doesn't seem to cover in that much detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much a new solution as a more detailed version of what you already wrote and that hopefully clears up some  of your questions

Consider the sum for some arbitrary permuation $\sigma$ and introduce the sets $S$ and $T$ by
$$
S = \{1 \leq i \leq n | \sigma(i) \geq i\}
$$
$$
T = \{1 \leq i \leq n | \sigma(i) < i\}
$$
which implies that $S \cup T = \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ and that for the size of the we have |S| + |T| = n. Then we can rewrite the sum as
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n | \sigma(i) - i |
& = \sum_{i \in S} \left| \sigma(i) - i \right| + \sum_{i \in T} \left| \sigma(i) - i \right| \\
& = \sum_{i \in S} \left( \sigma(i) - i \right) + \sum_{i \in T} \left( i - \sigma(i) \right) \\
& = \left( \sum_{i \in S} \sigma(i) + \sum_{i \in T} i \right) - \left( \sum_{i \in S} i + \sum_{i \in T} \sigma(i) \right)
\end{eqnarray}

In each of the four sums the terms are distinct and a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. In the two left-hand sums together we have $n$ terms of the multiset $M=\{1,1,2,2,\dots,n,n\}$ and hence we know that
the sum can not be larger than the $n$ largest elements of $M$
$$
\sum_{i \in S} \sigma(i) + \sum_{i \in T} i \leq \frac{n+1}{2} + \frac{n+3}{2} + \frac{n+3}{2} + \dots + n + n = \frac{(n+1)(3n-1)}{4} \qquad (*)
$$
Likewise, the two right-hand sums can not be smaller than the $n$ smallest elements of $M$
$$
\sum_{i \in S} i + \sum_{i \in T} \sigma(i) \geq 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 \dots + \frac{n-1}{2} + \frac{n-1}{2} + \frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} \qquad (**)
$$
and hence we find that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n | \sigma(i) - i | \leq \frac{(n+1)(3n-1)}{4}  -  \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} = \frac{n^2-1}{2}
$$
This is an upper bound for the sum and we just need to show that it can be reached, which is the case for the permutation $\sigma(i)=n+1-i$.

This proofs the maximum value and answers your first question.

Since the elements in either sum of $(*)$ are distinct, there are only two possibilities in which a permutation can reach the maximum in $(*)$

1. $\{\sigma(i) | i \in S\} = \{\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+3}{2},\dots,n\}$
   and $T = \{\frac{n+3}{2},\frac{n+5}{2},\dots,n\}$

   Since we defined $S$ and $T$ such that if $i \in S$ than $i \notin T$, it then follows that

   $S = \{1,2,\dots,\frac{n+1}{2} \}$ and
   $\{\sigma(i) | i \in T\} = \{1,2,\dots,\frac{n-1}{2}\}$

   Hence

   $$\{\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(\frac{n+1}{2})\} = \{\frac{n+1}{2},\dots,n\}$$
   $$\{\sigma(\frac{n+3}{2}),\dots,\sigma(n)\} = \{1,\dots,\frac{n-1}{2}\}$$
2. $\{\sigma(i) | i \in S\} = \{\frac{n+3}{2},\frac{n+5}{2},\dots,n\}$
   and
   $T = \{\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+3}{2},\dots,n\}$

   Since we defined $S$ and $T$ such that if $i \in S$ than $i \notin T$, it then follows that

   $S = \{1,2,\dots,\frac{n-1}{2}\}$
   and
   $\{\sigma(i) | i \in T\} = \{1,2,\dots,\frac{n+1}{2}\}$

   Hence

   $$\{\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(\frac{n-1}{2})\} = \{\frac{n+3}{2},\dots,n\}$$
   $$\{\sigma(\frac{n+1}{2}),\dots,\sigma(n)\} = \{1,\dots,\frac{n+1}{2}\}$$

Combining the result of these both posibilities gives indeed

$$\{\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(\frac{n-1}{2})\} \subset \{\frac{n+1}{2},\dots,n\}$$
$$\{\sigma(\frac{n+3}{2}),\dots,\sigma(n)\} \subset \{1,\dots,\frac{n+1}{2}\}$$

Which gives the answer to your second question. (Note there was a small typo , $\sigma((n+2)/2)$ should have been  $\sigma((n+3)/2)$)

In order to confirm that all these permutations are correct and result in the maximum sum, we need to check that they satisfy the definition of $S$ given by $S = \{1 \leq i \leq n | \sigma(i) \geq i\}$ so that each of the terms $|\sigma(i) -i|$ is correctly rewritten.

1. for $1 \leq i \leq \frac{n+1}{2}$ we have $\sigma(i) \geq \frac{n+1}{2} \geq i$

   for $\frac{n+3}{2} \leq i \leq n$ we have $\sigma(i) \leq \frac{n-1}{2} < i$
2. for $1 \leq i \leq \frac{n-1}{2}$ we have $\sigma(i) \geq \frac{n+3}{2} > i$

   for $\frac{n+1}{2} \leq i \leq n$ we have $\sigma(i) \leq \frac{n+1}{2} \leq i$

In the last case equality could occur, but only for one term in the sum,i.e.  $\sigma(\frac{n+1}{2})=\frac{n+1}{2}$. Permutations that include this particular pair, however, are not new permutations, but ones that were already included under 1).

I hope this answers your third question.